# links with $ signs handled ambiguously

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering, markdown-preview

It appears that links like http://nginx.org/r/$uri are shown with the `$uri` part being part of the link during the live preview (JavaScript), yet not when shown statically on the page (server-side).

This results in the live preview giving a false impression.  Sounds like the server side should be fixed to allow the $ sign within literal links.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33592218/1122270

Comment: @ShadowWizard, no, that question makes no mention of the preview showing it as a full link

Comment: True. Retracted. Cheers!